# Group by one table and sum from another table in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Linq query:

```
from i in data.Items
join tdi in data.TDItems on i.itemId equals tdi.itemId
group i by i.ItemId
into selection 
select new
{
    itemId = selection.Key
    number = selection.Sum(x => x.quantity) // quantity is a field in TDItems
}
```

How do I create this sum function? because I'm grouping by an attribute in the Items table, I can't call a Sum on the TDItems table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
group new { i, tdi } by i.ItemId
...
select new 
{
   selection.Sum(x => x.tdi.quantity)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          from c in (from i in @as 
                join tdi in bs on i.itemId equals tdi.itemId
        select new
        {
            itemId = i.itemId,
            quantity = tdi.quantity
        })
        group c by c.itemId
        into selection
        select new
        {
            itemId = selection.Key,
            number = selection.Sum(x => x.quantity) // quantity is a field in TDItems
        };
```